# Facebook comments - wordpress

Tags: html, css, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I implanted facebook comments widget in my site.

Created an test app for site development and implanted this code after

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=737848022908232";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then in necessary place wrote this.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://marker.s45.webhost1.ru/blog/" data-width="910"></div>
</div>
```

There are two problems

1)If i comment on one post, the comment will show on every post
- I want every post to have their own comments

2)When i comment on the post, in my fb profile doesnt show that i just commented.. It should

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `data-href` needs to be an absolute and unique URL for the particular blog post, like so -

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-width="910"></div>
```

See the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) for documentation on `the_permalink`.

2) For your comment to display on your Facebook Profile you must tick the 'Post to Facebook' checkbox - see the [Facebook Comments Widget](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)  documentation.